# The "--platforms" argument is not supported in module template

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-desktop

A brand new Flutter Project created in VSCode throws the above error when I try to run it on Windows. Detailed steps to reproduce below:

1. I created a new default Flutter application in VSCode.
2. I ran `flutter config --enable-windows-desktop`
3. I ran `flutter devices`.

`Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1766] Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.66 Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 103.0.1264.44`

4. I ran the app in Vscode without debugging and chose `Enable Windows for this Project`.
   It reported the error below.

   `flutter create --platforms windows . The "--platforms" argument is not supported in module template. exit code 2`
5. `flutter doctor` output:

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1766], locale en-GB)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.0.6)

[√] Android Studio (version 4.2)

[√] VS Code (version 1.68.1)

[√] Connected device (3 available)

[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!

Edit: I recreated the applitaion from the command line and it ran through without problems. Looks like whatever the problem is, it's coming from VSCode